# How to get user input as date format

Tags: python, date, datetime, user-interface, strftime

I am trying to create a program to handle my finances, and one issue I always seem to have is not being able to input a date from the user interface, then subtracting or adding it to the current date to determine if it is overdue or coming soon.

How can I achieve this?

I tried converting the string to an int and float, and it comes up with a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(date here)'.

```
date = datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
show_str("Today's date is:\n-> " + str(date) +"\n")

biller_name = get_str("What is the billers name?\n-> ")

due_date = get_int("When is your bill due?\n(Enter date as \"DD/MM/YYYY\")\n-> ")
if due_date < date:
    userDate = datetime(due_date)
    x = userDate - date
    print(x)
```

Comment: `date` *is* a str; there is neither any need to call `str(date)` in the call to `show_str` nor any expectation that the return value of `get_int` (I would think it's an `int`) is comparable to that `str` value.

Comment: `datetime` objects are comparable; you probably want `date` to be the return value of `datetime.today()`, call `show_str(date.strftime("Today's date is\n-> %d/%m/%Y\n'))`, and make `due_date` a `datetime` object as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `datetime` object you can easily check for **due or coming soon**.

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"

usr_input=input("When is your bill due?\n(Enter date as \"DD/MM/YYYY\")\n-> ")

today_date=datetime.today().strftime(date_format)
today_date = datetime.strptime(today_date, date_format)

due_date = datetime.strptime(usr_input, date_format)

x = abs(today_date-due_date)
if due_date<today_date:
    print(f"{x.days} Days Overdue")
elif due_date>today_date:
    print(f"{x.days} Days: Remaining")
else:
    print("Today is the last date")
```

**Output:**

```
When is your bill due?
(Enter date as "DD/MM/YYYY")
-> 04/02/2023
Today is the last date

When is your bill due?
(Enter date as "DD/MM/YYYY")
-> 08/09/2023
216 Days: Remaining

When is your bill due?
(Enter date as "DD/MM/YYYY")
-> 12/04/2022
298 Days Overdue
```

**Note*** I obtained in `days` if you wanted you can change as your desired.. [months, years etc.]

Comment: Thanks @Yash Mehta it has improved my code very much, i would like to figure out a way to store the overdue days as a negative number to a list, keeping the last day and days remaining as normal.

Comment: you can initialise a list as `days_overdue = []` and `append` in the list when this condition met `if due_date < today_date:`  do.. `days_overdue.append(-x.days)` and by printing you can see the list. `print(f"Days overdue: {days_overdue}")` @TechANam